# How to expose a Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this `Dockerfile` written.

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "python3", "-m http.server" ] //even tried CMD [ "python3", "-m", "http.server" ]
```

I built the image with this:

```
docker build -t --name server .
```

and I ran a container from the image like this:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name web server
```

But when I hit < host-url >:8080

It doesn't work.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: what does `docker container logs web` show? Any hint if the server is running?

Comment: You have set /usr/src/app as workdir, however I don't see any step for copying the files. Are you sure the code is present in /usr/src/app? 

Also you run docker ps -a, to check all the processes started,otherwise exited. Can you also paste the output here.

Comment: I have set the `/usr/src/app` as WORKDIR. And I am executing a CMD command which starts a simple server in localhost in a single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the Python SimpleHTTPServer which is served in port `8000` by default.

Either your `Dockerfile` should expose `8000` instead of `8080`

```
EXPOSE 8000
```

Or, change the command to run it in port `8080`

```
CMD ["python3", "-m",  "http.server", "8080"]
```